# set boundary limit for draggable pane inside its parent pane

Tags: java, javafx, pane

I have a draggable pane which is inside another pane. I want to make the child pane be draggable only inside the boundary of the parent pane but by default, the child pane can be dragged anywhere. How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this [demo](https://gist.github.com/zinch84/9863103). The application produces draggable labels which can be moved all around the scene. To set the boundary limit the following technique is used: inside the onMouseDragged handler we compute the current position of the node and if it does not satisfy some condition we don't modify it. Particularly:

```
label.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

      //Sets the drag boundaries limit
      double newX = mouseEvent.getSceneX() + dragDelta.x;
      if (newX > 200 || newX < 10) {
        return;
      }

      label.setLayoutX(mouseEvent.getSceneX() + dragDelta.x);
      label.setLayoutY(mouseEvent.getSceneY() + dragDelta.y);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Really thank you this works for me. But a problem in this code is if we keep the "if" statement, it will make the pane much slower than by removing it. I would be glad if solution to this problem will be provided.
Thank you

Comment: I think it is a partial answer. It answer "how do I limit" but ignores " inside the boundary of the parent pane"

Comment: Well, instead of hard coded values you can use properties, that depend on border pane boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [xuesheng answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22737093/3992939), instead of

```
 if (newX > 200 || newX < 10) { return; }
```

use

```
if( outSideParentBounds(label.getLayoutBounds(), newX, newY) ) {    return; }
```

Where `outSideParentBounds` is defined by:

```
private boolean outSideParentBounds( Bounds childBounds, double newX, double newY) {

        Bounds parentBounds = getLayoutBounds();

        //check if too left
        if( parentBounds.getMaxX() <= (newX + childBounds.getMaxX()) ) {
            return true ;
        }

        //check if too right
        if( parentBounds.getMinX() >= (newX + childBounds.getMinX()) ) {
            return true ;
        }

        //check if too down
        if( parentBounds.getMaxY() <= (newY + childBounds.getMaxY()) ) {
            return true ;
        }

        //check if too up
        if( parentBounds.getMinY() >= (newY + childBounds.getMinY()) ) {
            return true ;
        }

        return false;

        /* Alternative implementation 
        Point2D topLeft = new Point2D(newX + childBounds.getMinX(), newY + childBounds.getMinY());
        Point2D topRight = new Point2D(newX + childBounds.getMaxX(), newY + childBounds.getMinY());
        Point2D bottomLeft = new Point2D(newX + childBounds.getMinX(), newY + childBounds.getMaxY());
        Point2D bottomRight = new Point2D(newX + childBounds.getMaxX(), newY + childBounds.getMaxY());
        Bounds newBounds = BoundsUtils.createBoundingBox(topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight);

        return ! parentBounds.contains(newBounds);
         */
    }
```